# Python: Using CVXOPT for quadratic programming

Tags: python, optimization, quadratic

I'm using CVXOPT to do quadratic programming to compute the optimal weights of a potfolio using mean-variance optimization. There is a great example at http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/userguide/coneprog.html#quadratic-programming. However, the arguments are in a regularized form (according to the author). The example is a basic version. I am looking to do a bit of a more complex problem where:

```
min:

x'Sx  

s.t.:

x'a >= g  
x'1 = 0  
x >= -Wb  
x <= c1 - Wb  

where:
x: active weights of assets (active weight = portfolio weight - benchmark weight)  
S: covariance matrix of asset returns  
a: expected stock excess returns  
g: target gain  
Wb: weights of assets in the benchmark  
c: upper limit (weight) of any asset in the portfolio
```

Assume all the variables are computed or known.

The basic example presented in the documentation:

```
min:  

x'Sx  

s.t.  

p'x >= g  
1'x = 1
```

Where p are the asset returns.

What I do not know (referring to the code at http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/examples/book/portfolio.html and optimization problem above):

1.I think these arguments setup the constraints but I'm not entirely sure:

```
G = matrix(0.0, (n,n))
G[::n+1] = -1.0
h = matrix(0.0, (n,1))
A = matrix(1.0, (1,n))
b = matrix(1.0)
```

2.I believe this is part of the minimization problem in "regulated form", which I'm not sure what means:

```
mus = [ 10**(5.0*t/N-1.0) for t in xrange(N) ]
```

3.What the arguments to qp are (solver.qp is the quadratic optimizer):

```
xs = [ qp(mu*S, -pbar, G, h, A, b)['x'] for mu in mus ]
```

Looking at the documentation, I'm pretty sure that mu*S (the first argument) is the objective function to be minimzed and -pbar are the returns. This looks like a maximization problem however (maximizing negative returns).

I do not know, however how the other arguments are used.

I am looking for help using the optimizer given my minimization problem and constraints above.

Answer (score 1):

I read the docs and I think you have to use the function with the following parameters. I assume that `x` has size `n`:

```
P = S
q = (0,....0)

A = (1, ...... 1)
b = (0)
```

`G` is vertically stacked from

```
 -a
 +I_n
 -I_n
```

where `I_n` is the identity matrix of size `n x n` . And the corresponding right hand side `h` is

```
  -g
  Wb
  ...
  Wb
  C1-Wb
  ...
  C1-Wb
```

That is: one `-g`, `n` times `Wb` and `n` times `C1-Wb`.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not following for `G` and `h`... For `G`, what do you mean `-a, ... -a`? and `+I_n`? For `h`, I'm not clear at all. Also, what is your logic for your thoughts?

Comment: I just formulated your problem so that it matches the specification given by your link to cvxopt.

Comment: -a .... -a was wrong. I_n is the identity matrix of size n, that is the matrix is zero outside the diagonl. The diagonal contains only ones.

Comment: h is a vector. it's entries are given as I described it. The first entry is -g, then n times Wb, then n times "C1-Wb"